# Excel function to SUM all the values in a column except the last value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a weekly customer deposit amount in a column that includes empty value in between. How can i sum the amount in that column leaving the last cell value. The column is dynamic and next week more deposits come in that increases the Column length. Again i have to sum the entire values leaving the last cell value in that column. Please suggest excel function that automates this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `VLOOPKUP` to catch the last value and subtract it, without the need to generate intermediate arrays:

```
=SUM(A:A)-VLOOKUP(1E+99,A:A, 1)
```

p.s. unlike `VLOOKUP`, `LOOKUP` is provided for backward compatibility so should be used only when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like: 
    =SUM(A:A)-LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)

It would sum everything in that column and minus the last cell value, effectively excluding that one. NB: that should not be placed in the same column as may result in circular reference

Comment: This is a good solution, but I posted another one because I usually avoid `LOOKUP` (provided only for backward compatibility) and moreover we can avoid the calculation of a large intermediate array :)